# Password authentication failure

Tags: password, 23.04

Upon installing Ubuntu 23.04, I encountered difficulties with entering the password during login. Despite reinstalling the operating system and setting the password in alphanumeric form, the problem persists, making it challenging to access the system.

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I read through the "Password Authentication Problems" blog, hoping to find a suitable solution. I diligently followed all the recommended steps and suggestions outlined in the blog, but unfortunately, the problem still remains unresolved.
I have also taken some additional troubleshooting measures, such as verifying the keyboard layout, ensuring Caps Lock and Num Lock are not causing any input issues, and even attempting to use the on-screen keyboard, however these efforts did not yield any positive results.

Comment: You're a little short on details; Ubuntu 23.04 is in different products, with different installers (two for desktop, one for servers, and two depending on *flavors*) thus we don't know what you're specifically asking about. You mention a blog, but I did a search for an official wiki/help page with that name & results were none.  Why not provide a link, rather than vague or incomplete details?

Comment: "*difficulties entering the password*" could mean several possibilities. 1) You have some kind of keyboard or input issue, 2) You entered the wrong password (the system will tell you so), 3) You entered the correct password, but the desktop crashed. Since you used the on-screen keyboard and did not mention an "invalid password" message, this suggests you are suffering from #3. Try searching for "desktop crash" in the search box at the top of the page.